# Do you need restrict by IP the RDP port?

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, amazon-ec2

I have my Amazon server for 4+ years suddenly I couldn't connect by Remote Desktop. Customer Service said I need to restrict RDP port to just the connecting PC. I did add the firewall rule and start working again. But I don't have static IP address and in these times of Covid-19 and people working from home have someone changing the firewall rules, so people can connect doesn't seem practical.

So is really necessary to restrict RDP port because is weird suddenly stop working. Customer support said maybe is a DoS attack, but the web pages stored there were still working.

And is there a workaround to handle it in this with multiple users and dinamic IP.

Comment: Setup advanced logic on the RDP machine that checks the content of a file via FTP every x minutes or x hours and in that file you change the content to equal the new IP address. This way your IP changes and you cannot connect via RDP, you get your new IP, connect to the FTP and update the file with the new IP address. Then the next time the advanced logic runs and sees the IP is different, it then updates the FW rule with that IP address. If you must whitelist, that is a way around it that has been used successfully elsewhere.

Comment: Also, you could add your entire ISP's IP range to a whilelist. This still narrows down only the ISP public IP range to brute force your logins rather than the entire world which is better than everything. You'd want to have local user accounts with 14+ character complex passwords. Using VPN is the best though in my opinion and you do not need to open up any ports for direct RDP access to servers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of debate whether it is really necessary, but there is definitely a good reason for having some form of protection.

We live in a digital age, and if you have RDP access to a server, hackers will scan the internet continuously finding machines to find servers with RDP open. Once they find it, they will hack the server using various methods and once they are in, they will install a cryptolocker hijacking virus and demand money to release your machine.

I've seen it happen more and more in the last 2 years so it really is necessary to put in some form of protection, as just your username and password is not enough. There is a strategy to have different ports, and this will keep out the majority of hackers, but the really determined ones will still find you, so this is only delaying the hacking attempt.

True protections come in the form of setting up a whitelisted IP to which you can connect from, or setup a VPN solution. Alternative solutions that work well are RDP firewalls that will ban ip adresses automatically after 5 failed login attempts. This is the strategy I usually go for because it allows the most flexibility while still offering very good security. The downside of this over a whitelisted IP approach is that hackers still find your server and can choose to break in by continuously trying different passwords from different servers which basically means they're doing DoS attack on your server. Only the major players will be able to launch such attack, but they are getting more and more present.

You can talk with your hoster and ask if something like RDP Defender or RDP Guard is acceptable by them.